# NestJS - Testing a TCP microservice

Tags: testing, tcp, microservices, nestjs

Are there any examples of testing NestJS TCP services? I have got my REST API testing using supertest, something similar for TCP sockets?

Answer (score 0):

`supertest` is [using](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest/blob/master/lib/test.js#L61) [server.listen(0)](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_listen_port_host_backlog_callback) method underhood. It binds server to free random port, and using it in request address for `superagent`.

So you can create your own library with the same principe, or simply look at [test-tcp](https://github.com/sugyan/node-test-tcp)